# Turtle Graphics window not responding

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, fractals

I am attempting to translate a Julia set generator that I made previously to Python code. However, when the code is run, the turtle graphics window stops responding immediately and draws nothing. Have I done something horribly wrong or is there something I'm missing? Perhaps I'm asking too much of python to do in 1 frame. Please explain what is causing this to happen and how I can fix it. Thanks!

```
import turtle
import time

y_set = []
map_output = 0
iterations = 0
#turtle.hideturtle()
#turtle.speed(1)
```

generate a list of y-values

```
def y_set (r):
    global y_set
    y_set = []
    for n in range ((360*2)+1):
        y_set.append(n)
```

create a color value

```
def color (i, n):
    output = map(i, 2, 10000, 0, 2500)
    if output < 0:
        output = 0
    if output > 0:
        output = 255
```

iterate on the x's

```
def repeat (n, r, i):
    global iterations
    global x
    global y
    aa = 0
    ba = 0
    ab = 0
    a = 0
    b = 0
    for j in range (n):
        iterations += 1
        aa = a * a
        bb = b * b
        ab = 2 * a * b
        a = ((aa - bb) + float(r))
        b = (ab + float(i))
        if (ab + bb) > 4:
            break
    turtle.setx(100 * x)
    turtle.sety(100 * y)
    color(iterations, n)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.penup()
```

Iterate on the y's

```
def Julia (s, r, i, d):
    global iterations
    global y_set
    global x
    global y
    global a
    global b
    y_set(s)
    while len(y_set) > 0:
        y = y_set[0]/360
        del y_set[0]
        x = -1.5
        for n in range (round((700/(float(r)+1))+1)):
            a = x
            b = y
            iterations = 0
            repeat(10**d, r, i)
            x += ((1/240)*s)
```

user input

```
real = input('Real: ')
imag = input('Imaginary: ')

Julia (1, real, imag, 100)
turtle.done()
```

Comment: What to you expect the `map(i, 2, 10000, 0, 2500)` to do?

Comment: I expected map to take a number 'i' within range 2 to 10000, and map it to a new range 0 to 2500. Is that not what this function is?

Comment: No, that's not what the built-in `map()` function does—although you might be able to use it to implement your own function that will. Strongly suggest you read its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many problems with this code to focus on an algorithm error.  When I try to run it, I get, `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.  Specific issues:

The `i` argument here is being passed a number:

```
    iterations += 1
...
color(iterations, n)
...

def color(i, n):
    output = map(i, 2, 10000, 0, 2500)
```

but Python's `map` function (and Julia's) expects a function as its first argument:

```
map(func, *iterables)
```

and it returns a list of the results of applying `func` to `iterables` but you treat the result as a scalar value:

```
output = map(i, 2, 10000, 0, 2500)
if output < 0:
    output = 0
if output > 0:
    output = 255
```

The `color()` function never uses its second argument, and never returns anything!

The variables `a` & `b` here are being treated as globals, set but not used, as if prepared for use by `repeat()`:

```
global a
global b

...

a = x
b = y
iterations = 0
repeat(10 ** d, r, i)
```

but the `a` & `b` used by `repeat()` are locals initialized to zero:

```
a = 0
b = 0
```

You have a function and global variable with the same name `y_set`!

And your globals are out of control.

Comment: It seems I misunderstood what the map function did. I thought it maped a number from one range to another. As for the color, I simply took out the 'n' for testing purposes. Also, whoops, didn't realise y-set was a function and a variable. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the help. But what do you mean by my globals are "out of control". This is the solution I have been using for over a year when it comes to letting 2 or more functions modify the same variable. Also, even after fixing everything else you brought up, the turtle graphics window still won't respond.

Comment: @Noah: Global variables are generally considered a poor programming practice. The article [Global Variables Are Bad](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad) describes some of the reasons why.

Comment: @NoahGehlhausen, globals-wise, consider `iterations`.  You make it a global and declare it as such but just before you call `repeat()` you always set it to zero.  That's no different than making it local to `repeat()` and tossing the global stuff.